# Delphi context help says "Cannot find the C:Program FilesBorlandDelphi7Helpd7.hlp file"

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, winhelp

My Delphi 7 installation started giving this error. The error message shows the correct help path, but with the backslashes removed. The Help files are present in the expected location (C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Help).
I'm running D7 under Windows 7. It was working previously.

[image]

Sometimes I also get this error :

[image]

I have searched on Google, and I find others reported the problem, but no solution has been posted.

Comment: I would try to search the system registry (`regedit`) for the string "filesborlanddelphi". If there is a match, correct it there.

Comment: Eek! Something is messed up. This looks like a C parser attacking your backslashes!

Comment: @David, more like an import from a hacked reg-file where somebody forgot to double up the backslashes...

Comment: I have seen Delphi 7 give this error message. Something inside Delphi codebase "ate the backslashes".

Comment: Do you have the WinHlp add-on for Windows 7 installed?

Comment: Yes the WinHLP add-on KB917607 is already installed

Comment: The string "filesborlanddelphi" does not appear anywhere in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this error can be cause by help files missing from OpenHelp project.
To replicate error I would just add {$WARN} to simple project and press F1 on WARN word.
To fix it:

- run delphi 7
- click Help->Customize (OpenHelp window will be shown)
- in OpenHelp for each of "Context", "Index" and "Link" tabs:

  - select tab
  - browse to C:\program files\borland\delphi7\help (or whatever your delphi installation path is)
  - select missing files (in my case it was d7dopts.toc, d7dopts.hlp, d7derrs.toc and d7derrs.hlp)
  - save project